# How do I get the coordinates of a sprite after it has been acted on by a body (Android AndEngine)?

Tags: android, sprite, center, andengine

I'm using AndEngine to make a game. The user creates a sprite when they touch the screen and can drag it around. Once he lifts his finger, the sprite is attached with a physics body so that it falls to the bottom of the screen and reacts with the other sprites that have been created. I need to figure out when the sprite created hits another sprite, however. Since they are circles, I cannot use collideswith(). I am trying to just use the distnace formula to see when they touch, but I need to get the center coordinates of the sprites that have already been created. If I use, for example, mySprite[0].getX(), (0 being a sprite that has already been created) it returns the X value of the sprite just before the body was attached to it. How do I find the coordinates of the center as the sprites end up on the ground and bounce off one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to set contact listener for detecting the collision of you pivot body to other body as well as ground body. You have to get body position using mBody.getPosition() 
method and convert it into screen coordinate using PhysicsConstant.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO.